# Shiny reactivity with IncludeMarkdown?

Tags: html, r, shiny

Trying to take these ideas a step further:

- [HTML/Text/Markdown in Shiny](http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/including-html-text-and-markdown-files.html)
- [Render Images](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/images.html)

I want to include a reactive markdown file (`*.Md`) in a `mainPanel` conditional on the input to a `selectInput`. How do I do it?

I've tried variations on `renderText`, `renderPrint` and using `eval` inside `includeMarkdown`. Nothing seems to work so far.

EG.

```
### ui.R

shinyUI(fluidPage(    
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput("var1",
                  label= "Please Select option",
                  choices= c("option1", "option2", "option3"),
                  selected= "option1"
    ),

    mainPanel(
      h3("guide:")
      includeMarkdown("md_file")
    )
  )
))

### server.R
shinyServer(function(input, output) {

   output$md_file <- 
     if (input$var1 == "option1") {
       renderPrint({"option1.Md"})
     } else if (input$var1 == "option2") {
       renderPrint({"option2.Md"})
     } (input$var1 == "option3") {
       renderPrint({"option3.Md"})
     }
   })
})


R> shiny::runApp('C:/Shiny_demo')
```

> Listening on http://127.0.0.1:6421 
>   Warning in readLines(con) : 
>    cannot open file 'md_file': No such file or directory 
>   Error in readLines(con) : cannot open the connection

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on a discussion with Joe Cheng in the Shiny Google group, the answer is:

In your UI:

```
uiOutput("md_file")
```

In your server:

```
output$md_file <- renderUI({
  file <- switch(input$var1,
    option1 = "option1.Md",
    option2 = "option2.Md",
    option2 = "option3.Md",
    stop("Unknown option")
  )
  includeMarkdown(file)
})
```

Thanks, Joe!